# vbs all user desktop folder

Tags: file, scripting, vbscript, windows-scripting

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurrentDirectory = objShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentDirectory)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strCurrentDirectory = objShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")
```

The script crashes on the last line

The error message is

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error (59,
>   1) : Object doesn't support this
>   property or method:
>   'objShell.SpecialFolders'
>
> * script completed - exit code: 259 ***

I used http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_display_special_folder_locations.aspx as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ObjShell` is a `WScript.Shell` you can access its implemented `SpecialFolders` but you then reassign it to an instance `Shell.Application` which does not implement `SpecialFolders`, hence the error.

```
strCurrentDirectory = objShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")
```

retrieves the path, then:

```
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentDirectory)
```

fetches it as a shell item, for example after that:

```
msgbox objFolder.Title
```

would echo `"Desktop"`